# How can I apply my code on the sidebar? WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I would like to add custom code on sidebar, I have created a code that calculates the price of a product in 12 instalments.

This code appears under the cart button, but i would like this code to appear on a custom sidebar, is it possible?

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'show_installments', 20 );
function show_installments() {
    global $product; 
    $id = $product->get_id();
    $product = wc_get_product( $id );
    $a=$product->get_price();
    $b   = 12;
    $min = 25;
    $c   = round($a/$b,2);

    if ($a > $min)  {
        echo '<p class="p2_installments_12months">Purchase with'.$c.'€ per month for 12 months </p>';
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a quick workaround way that I did on my site with something similar.  I used this plugin to add php code as a widget.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/php-code-widget/

Then just change your code to this and toss the widget wherever you'd like the code to run.

```
<?php 

    global $product; 
    $id = $product->get_id();
    $product = wc_get_product( $id );
    $a=$product->get_price();
    $b   = 12;
    $min = 25;
    $c   = round($a/$b,2);

    if ($a > $min)  {
        echo '<p class="p2_installments_12months">Purchase with'.$c.'€ per month for 12 months </p>';
    }   

 ?>
```